# TextOut Function with variable not updating

Tags: c++, winapi

I am making a Desktop Application in VS 2019, and trying to print the variable `x` with `TextOut`. I know the problem is not in the way I'm altering the x variable, because it outputs it correctly with `OutputDebugString`. What am I doing wrong with `TextOut`?

Here is the relevant part of my code:

```cpp
case WM_PAINT:
    {
        float x = 1;
        while (x < 100) {
            x = x + 0.01;

            PAINTSTRUCT ps;
            HDC hdc = BeginPaint(hWnd, &ps);
            std::string s = std::to_string(x);
            std::wstring stemp = s2ws(s);
            LPCWSTR sw = stemp.c_str();
            OutputDebugString(sw);
            TextOut(hdc, x * 100, 150, sw, 3);
            EndPaint(hWnd, &ps);
        }
    }
```

I expect slowly increasing numbers (1.01, 1.02, 1.03, etc. ) that stops at 100, but instead I get a stagnant `1.0` in the window. Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: As far as I remember, `WM_PAINT` redraws only the part of the window that need to be redrawn (e.g. was covered by other window). Maybe that's the problem.

Comment: Using floating point for the coordinates is dodgy. Better to do the coordinates in integer arithmetic and then divide by 100 when generating the string. Also, you can't ever see 0.01 because x start at 1.0.

Comment: You might want to check that the string you're outputting actually is at least 3 characters long.  I suppose `std::to_wstring` might guarantee that for a float, at least in the "C" locale, but I don't know if that's true for all locales.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to call `(Begin|End)Paint()` only one time per `WM_PAINT` message. This is because `BeginPaint()` clips the drawing region to include only the areas that have been invalidated, and then validates the window. So in your example, the 2nd and subsequent iterations of the loop will not have anywhere to draw since the clipping region will be empty.

You need to move the calls to `(Begin|End)Paint()` outside of your loop.

There is also no need to manually convert your `std::string` data to `std::wstring`, just use the ANSI versions of `OutputDebugString()` and `TextOut()` and let them convert to Unicode internally for you.

```
case WM_PAINT: {
    PAINTSTRUCT ps;
    HDC hdc = BeginPaint(hWnd, &ps);

    float x = 1;
    while (x < 100) {
        x = x + 0.01;
        std::string s = std::to_string(x);
        OutputDebugStringA(s.c_str());
        TextOutA(hdc, x * 100, 150, s.c_str(), 3);
    }

    EndPaint(hWnd, &ps);
    break;
}
```

If you really want to use `std::wstring` then simply use `std::to_wstring()` instead of `std::to_string()`:

```
case WM_PAINT: {
    PAINTSTRUCT ps;
    HDC hdc = BeginPaint(hWnd, &ps);

    float x = 1;
    while (x < 100) {
        x = x + 0.01;
        std::wstring s = std::to_wstring(x);
        OutputDebugStringW(s.c_str());
        TextOutW(hdc, x * 100, 150, s.c_str(), 3);
    }

    EndPaint(hWnd, &ps);
    break;
}
```

Comment: [The `BeginPaint` function automatically validates the entire client area](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/desktop/api/winuser/nf-winuser-validaterect) (not `EndPaint`). Also worth a mention: A busy (re-)paint loop inside a `WM_PAINT` handler is problematic. It may or may not produce the desired result, and certainly causes the application to appear unresponsive to both the OS and the user.